# Values getting modified in the class during the runtime

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I am trying to loop around the value that already got populated in Registration class. I have already put a breakpoint in `getInstance()` method in Registration class. When the cursor reaches the below for loop code.

```
for (final Registration.HolderEntry entry : Registration.getInstance()) {
        // do other things..
}
```

I do a F5 on that. And then it gooes to `getInstance()` method of Registration class (below is the class). And when I inspect on `instance` variable at that point, I always see values populated in `listOfBundles` list which is good.

But if I keep on pressing F5 again, at some point it comes to `iterator` method in Registration class and then if I inspect on `listOfBundles list`, I don't see any values in that list which is what I am not able to understand why it is happening like this. No other code is running which might change the value of `listOfBundles`.

```
public class Registration implements Iterable<Registration.HolderEntry> {

    private List<String> listOfBundles = new LinkedList<String>();
    private final Map<String, HolderEntry> bundleMapper = new HashMap<String, HolderEntry>();


    private Registration() {
        //
    }

    private static class BundlesHolder {
        static final Registration instance = new Registration();
    }

    public static Registration getInstance() {
        return BundlesHolder.instance;
    }   

    public synchronized void registerBundles(final String bundleName, final IBundleCollection collection) {

        HolderEntry bundleHolder = new HolderEntry(bundleName, collection);

        bundleMapper.put(bundleName, bundleHolder);
        listOfBundles.add(bundleName);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Iterator<HolderEntry> iterator() {

        List<String> lst = new LinkedList<String>(listOfBundles);
        List<HolderEntry> list = new LinkedList<HolderEntry>();
        for (String clName : lst) {
            if (bundleMapper.containsKey(clName)) {
                list.add(bundleMapper.get(clName));
            }
        }

        Collections.reverse(list);
        return list.iterator();
    }

    // some other code
}
```

I hope the question is clear enough. Can anybody tell me what wrong I am going here?

Comment: because you use static instance always return same object public static Registration getInstance() method. (only one time  Registration is initialize). there are no different object is your iteration. same object is iterating on your iteration. its not applying to every object changes u make while iterate but it is same object you iterate and change values.
<BR>I dont know your real requirement. but try to use this.
public static Registration getInstance() {
        return new Registration();;
    }

Answer (score 0):

because you use static instance always return same object from

```
 public static Registration getInstance()
```

method. (only one time  Registration is initialize).

there are no different object is your iteration. same object is iterating on your iteration. its not like applying to every object changes you make while iterate but it is same object you iterate and change values.

I dont know your real requirement. but try to use this.

```
public static Registration getInstance() {
        return new Registration();;
    }
```